# How to change UDP port 1434 ms-sql-m service

Tags: sql-server

I am running sage evolution 200 on a cloud server. Until recently the program was running fine. Then the cloud host decided to block UDP port 1434 on their router as they claim it was being attacked. When I use port query, it return TCP port 1433 is listening but port 1434 is filtered. I contacted my cloud server provider and was advised to change port 1434 to another port number. I am not a computer expert by any means and need assistance is changing this port even though it's the official port for SQL Server.

Comment: See: [Is a Named Instance more Secure than the Default Instance?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/8008/is-a-named-instance-more-secure-than-the-default-instance). You can't change the browser port. Your options are: make your provider change their firewall rules or change the provider.

Comment: If the instance is listening on TCP 1433, you should be able to connect specifying only host name or IP address. UDP port 1434 is not needed in that case.